# How to add mouse multiselection support to Winform listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, multi-select, onmouseover

I need to add mouse multiselection support to a winform listview. (User will click one item and drag it to fifth and she'll be able to select items 1 to 5) I think I should inherit the listview to add new features to it but i don't know  which events or methods should i add. How can i do it? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make custom `ListView` of and override `MouseMove` (bonus - <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> support):

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // easy mouse selection
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var item = this.HitTest(e.Location).Item;
            if (item != null)
                item.Selected = true;
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // ctrl-a - select all
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control)
            SelectAll();
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

It's not the best implementation, if you move too fast, then some items will be skipped.

### Some explanations

`ListView` is a bit special control, because it has different views to present data. In *icon* view you select multiple items by *drawing a rectangle with mouse* (press button, draw rectangle, release). Same works in *details* view.  All intersected by rectangle items will be selected. Important: this way of selection required to draw rectangle starting from **unoccupied by items** area.

Problem: in *details* view unoccupied area located to the right of last column and to the bottom of last item. Often columns take all horizontal space, items take all vertical, so there is no such area exists then. So this way of selection will not work!

Other well known possibility to to select multiple items in `ListView` is to select first item, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then click on last item. All items in the range (or rectangle in *icon* view) will be selected. Or keep <kbd>Ctr</kbd> pressed and click items to toggle their selection one by one.

Comment: thanks, i will try it and inform you (accept the answer or not). thanks again for help.

Comment: Sinatr, as you said if I move the mouse too fast, some items aren't selected. how can i solve this issue? can you give me a hint or a tutorial to research etc?

Comment: See edit, I explained selection in `ListView`. I don't know an easy solution to avoid skipping items. Maybe you can process `SelectionChanged` event (which I hope doesn't skip selection) and see if mouse button is pressed, then add to selection what was already selected before (store it in the list, which is cleared after mouse button is released).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. BTW it could be done directly with ListView MouseMove event if you do not like to override the ListView class. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sinatrs approach is a good idea.

With 'Details' view you can try something like this, to get a Windows Explorer like behaviour:

```
    Int32 firstClickItemIndex = 0;

    public Boolean numInRange(Int32 num, Int32 first, Int32 last)
    {
        return first <= num && num <= last;
    }       

    private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem lvItem in listView1.Items)
                lvItem.Selected = true;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left && listView1.HitTest(e.Location).Item != null)
            firstClickItemIndex = listView1.HitTest(e.Location).Item.Index;            
    }

    private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ListViewItem lvItem = listView1.HitTest(e.Location).Item;
            if (lvItem != null)
            {
                lvItem.Selected = true;
                if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
                {
                    Int32 firstSelected = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
                    Int32 lastSelected = listView1.SelectedItems[listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index;
                    foreach (ListViewItem tempLvItem in listView1.Items)
                    {
                        if (numInRange(tempLvItem.Index, firstSelected, lastSelected) && (numInRange(tempLvItem.Index, lvItem.Index, firstClickItemIndex) || numInRange(tempLvItem.Index, firstClickItemIndex, lvItem.Index)))
                        {
                            tempLvItem.Selected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tempLvItem.Selected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```